# Move a box through the corners of a square, then move it in a snake pattern

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I want the box to move in these directions as shown

[image: in the picture]

and I want the box to move in these directions as shown

[image: in the picture]

This is my code:

```js
function myMove1() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("box1");
    var pos = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

    function frame() {
        if (pos == 350) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            pos++;
            elem.style.left = pos + "px";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#Container1{
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
position: relative;
background-color:thistle
}
#box1{
width:50px;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
background-color:teal;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myMove1()">MoveLeft</button>
        <div id="Container1">
<div id="box1"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: there's no function called `myMove1` - that's why the error is `ReferenceError: myMove1 is not defined`

Comment: @JaromandaX I Edit The Code

Answer (score 0):

#### First script live example:

```js
function myMove1() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("box1");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
      myMove2();
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.left = pos + "px";
    }
  }
}

function myMove2() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("box1");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
      myMove3();
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + "px";
    }
  }
}

function myMove3() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("box1");
  var pos = 350;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 0) {
      clearInterval(id);
      myMove4();
    } else {
      pos--;
      elem.style.left = pos + "px";
    }
  }
}

function myMove4() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("box1");
  var pos = 350;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 0) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos--;
      elem.style.top = pos + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#Container1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: thistle
}

#box1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myMove1()">MoveLeft</button>
<div id="Container1">
  <div id="box1"></div>
</div>
```

#### Second script live example:

```js
function myMove1() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("box1");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
      myMove2();
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.left = pos + "px";
    }
  }
}

function myMove2() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("box1");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 117) {
      clearInterval(id);
      myMove3();
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + "px";
    }
  }
}

function myMove3() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("box1");
  var pos = 350;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 0) {
      clearInterval(id);
      myMove4();
    } else {
      pos--;
      elem.style.left = pos + "px";
    }
  }
}

function myMove4() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("box1");
  var pos = 117;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 234) {
      clearInterval(id);
      myMove5();
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + "px";
    }
  }
}

function myMove5() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("box1");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
      myMove6();
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.left = pos + "px";
    }
  }
}

function myMove6() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("box1");
  var pos = 234;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
      myMove7();
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + "px";
    }
  }
}

function myMove7() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("box1");
  var pos = 350;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 0) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos--;
      elem.style.left = pos + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#Container1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: thistle
}

#box1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myMove1()">MoveLeft</button>
<div id="Container1">
  <div id="box1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: please answer task 2

Comment: @AhmedIbrahimTV I added the second example. If helped, please vote up this answer. Thank you!

Comment: This was a quick response and this code can and should be optimized and reduced.